# Easy way to draw a Perpendicular lines on Console in C# with given Symbols

Tags: c#, ascii-art

Is there any easy way or APIS to draw the boxes or line in C# on console from symbols - /,| and _ or -.
For example I want to draw something like this :

```
     ^
     |
     |
     |
     |___________>
    /
   /
  /
```

I can draw two lines but not third one with "/" to look like above figure.I need an arrow as well at the end but it is I think nearly impossible.

Below is my dirty code :

```
    Console.WriteLine("\t\t^Z");
    Console.WriteLine("\t\t|");
    Console.WriteLine("\t\t|");
    Console.WriteLine("\t\t|");
    Console.WriteLine("\t\t|");
    Console.WriteLine("\t\t|");

    Console.WriteLine("\t\t         X");
    Console.WriteLine("\t\t -------->");
    Console.WriteLine("\t       /");
    Console.WriteLine("\t      /");
    Console.WriteLine("\t     /");
    Console.WriteLine("\t    /");
    Console.WriteLine("\t   /");
```

Comment: I guess you could use `PadLeft(lengthOfZAxis, " ")`, but really if you need something graphical, the console window isn't the best place for it

Comment: How about a letter "L"? :) By the way this seems to be off topic, this is an ASCII art question, not programming.

Comment: L is good , But i need orthogonal axis basically.X,Y and Z in all possible orientation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if its any prettier but you could use `PadLeft` and make a method to do it

[IDEOne Example](https://ideone.com/4BjNTk)

```
public static void MakeAxis(int lineLengths)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < lineLengths - 1; i++)
        Console.WriteLine("|".PadLeft(lineLengths, ' '));
    Console.WriteLine("|".PadLeft(lineLengths, ' ') + new String('_', lineLengths<<1));
    for(int i = lineLengths; i > 0; i--)
        Console.WriteLine("/".PadLeft(i, ' '));
}
```

Example output

```
  |
  |
  |______
  /
 /
/
```